# c# QuadTree yielding properly

Tags: c#, iterator, quadtree, yield-return

I have implemented a QuadTree of my own, and I'm afraid I didn't use yield properly when I query my tree,
my fear is that I create O(HN) iterators.

Could you direct me how to better improve the performance of the following code?

QuadTree

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(string leafId, Circle shape)
    {
        // Gets the relevant parent by a leafId Query (this is O(lg H))
        var startNode = GetParentIntersecting(leafId, shape);

        return startNode.Query(shape);
    }
```

QuadTreeNode

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Query(IShape shape)
    {
        var results = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (var content in _contents)
        {
            if (shape.Contains(content.GetPosition()))
            {
                //Debug.Log(content.GetPosition());
                yield return content;
                //results.Add(content);
            }
        }

        if (IsLeaf)
            yield break;

        foreach (var node in Nodes)
        {
            if (node.IsEmpty && node.IsLeaf)
                continue;

            foreach (var result in node.Query(shape))
            {
                results.Add(result);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is working code, but you want comments on improving it, you should be using [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks I wasn't aware this existed I will post it there